# IF else statement function

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax

i have this code of if else statement

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int aInt = Integer.parseInt(textView1.getText().toString());
             if(aInt <= 0) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else{

                 int a=Integer.parseInt(textView1.getText().toString());
                     int  b=a-2;
                  String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
                 textView1.setText(s1);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int c =Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                        int d = c-1;
                        String s2 = String.valueOf(d);
                        textView5.setText(s2);

                }  if(textView5 != null) {
                    int dInt = Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                        if(dInt <= 0);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Fifth.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    SavePreferences("MEM1", textView1.getText().toString());
                }
        }

};
```

on this part of the code i want to start the intent if the value of textView5 is 0
but it still goes to the new intent even the value of textView5 is not yet 0 i don`t know what part of my code is wrong:

```
}  if(textView5 != null) {
                int dInt = Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                    if(dInt <= 0);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Fifth.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Comment: use `if(dInt <= 0)` instead of `if(dInt <= 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(textView5 != null)
{
      int dInt = Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
      if(dInt <= 0)
                {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fifth.class));
                }
     }
```

Comment: If my answer help, you can also upvote and accept my answer, that will help to another user to sort out same problem with them.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
}  if(textView5 != null) {
            int dInt = Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                if(dInt <= 0) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Fifth.class);
                startActivity(intent);
              }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement **(textView5 != null) checks if view is not null**. You need to add edit the code like .

```
                   if(!textView5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            int dInt = Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                if(dInt <= 0);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Fifth.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: if loop without semi colon like this

```
  if(dInt <= 0){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Fifth.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

`;` is endof String. if you give `;` at end of If condition, then the body doesn't executed..

so remove it and check your code..

```
if(dInt <= 0)
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   ......
```